# Is it possible to hide the Steps section on the UI of Step Omniscript Component?

Tags: velocity

Hello I am trying to see if I can use CSS for my problem below. I would like to use Omniscript to simply display a custom LWC flexcard component. Would only need 1 step for this scenario.

Any help would be appreciated! Would like to know if it possible to hide the "Steps" section on the right hand side of the omniscript if you are simply displaying your components on one step?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EA3z.png)